# How can I substitute values into this set of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions, trigonometry

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to solve this set of trig equations (I'm not exactly sure if the syntax looks correct):

```
Solve[Tan[(delta + beta)/2] == nz*Tan[theta/2] && 
  ny*Tan[(delta - beta)/2] == nx && 
  Cos[(delta + beta)/2]*Cos[gamma/2] == Cos[theta/2], {delta, beta, 
  gamma}, Reals]
```

The goal is to solve for `delta, beta` and `gamma`. I want to substitute different values of `nx,ny,nz,theta` into these equations and get the solutions. How can I substitute those values in there? Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: Do you have conditions on the variables? If so maybe you can stick these into the system of equations and locate a possible general solution. Additionally, if you have all numerical inputs, then you should use `NSolve`.

Comment: @CA Trevillian Thanks for the comment! Yeah I'm hoping to make all the variables range from `[-pi,pi]` i.e. principal values. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: So you will want a solution that is valid for this region? If you wish to go numeric route you’ll need to choose a level of discretization. Look up `Assumptions` If you want to stay analytical and `NSolve` with `Table`, if you want to use numerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have nz, nx and ny reals, try this:

```
sol1 = Simplify[
   Solve[Tan[(delta + beta)/2] == nz*Tan[theta/2] /. 
      delta + beta -> x, x][[1, 1]], {C[1] == 0}] /. x -> delta + beta

(*  beta + delta -> 2 ArcTan[nz Tan[theta/2]]  *)

sol2 = Simplify[
   Solve[ny*Tan[(delta - beta)/2] == nx /. delta - beta -> y, y][[1, 
     1]], {C[1] == 0}] /. y -> delta - beta

(* -beta + delta -> 2 ArcTan[nx/ny]  *)

Simplify[Solve[Cos[(delta + beta)/2]*Cos[gamma/2] == Cos[theta/2], 
    gamma][[1, 1]], {C[1] == 0}] /. sol1

(*  gamma -> -2 ArcCos[Cos[theta/2] Sqrt[1 + nz^2 Tan[theta/2]^2]]  *)
```

And then

```
eq1 = Equal @@ sol1;
eq2 = Equal @@ sol2;
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {beta, delta}]

(*  {{beta -> -ArcTan[nx/ny] + ArcTan[nz Tan[theta/2]], 
  delta -> ArcTan[nx/ny] + ArcTan[nz Tan[theta/2]]}}    *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much! That's really helpful:)